# Regex capture substrings while omitting certain substring

Tags: regex

I want to use regex to capture color, animal, and country from the following html. However, with country, there is a **possibility** that a `<br>` tag exists before the country name, such as with SPAIN in my example. I want to omit that `<br>` tag, so that only "SPAIN" is captured.

```
<p><span class="w">RED</span><br><span class="a">DOG</span>USA</p>
<p><span class="w">GREEN</span><br><span class="a">CAT</span><br>SPAIN</p>
<p><span class="w">BLUE</span><br><span class="a">MOUSE</span>FRANCE</p>
```

I have the following regex, but it doesn't omit the country `<br>` tag:

```
/<p><span class="w">(.*)<\/span><br><span class="a">(.*)<\/span>(.*)<\/p>/
```

Please help.

Comment: `(?<=>)(?<color>\w+).*?(?<=>)(?<animal>\w+).*?(?<=>)(?<country>\w+)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<p><span class="w">(.*)<\/span><br><span class="a">(.*)<\/span>(?:<br>)?(.*)<\/p>
```

`(?:...)` : non-capturing group.

`?` : 0 or 1 times

check pattern: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/VasWQx/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to match only the content between `>` and `<`

```
(?<=>)([[:upper:]]+)(?=<)
```

[View Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CaifjA/2)